# How to compare two stl lists filled with classes

Tags: c++, list, stl

I am writing a program for my c++ class and i am stuck on a problem. For the project i had to make two teams of supers and preform a simulation of a battle. In my main.cpp I created two list for each team and filled them with a 3 classes representing 3 characters per team. In the classes, I have attributes and one of the attributes is 'double speed'. I sorted the two teams to make the first character of the list to have the fastest speed of each team and is followed by the next fastest. Now comes the part I am stuck on. I have to do the simulation now and have the fastest overall character goes first followed by the next fastest. First, I do not know how to add the opposite team into a list inside my class, and second, I do not know how to compare the list to see who goes first. I created a list within my class called

```
list<super*>target
```

Which is list of pointers. I tried to add the opposite team to my target list when I created the teams like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    hptr = new super;
    vptr = new super;

    TeamA.push_back(*hptr);
    TeamB.push_back(*vptr);

    hptr -> addtarget(vptr);
    vptr -> addtarget(hptr);
}
```

But I get an error in my addtarget function which is:

```
void super::addtarget(super *tptr){

target.push_back(*tptr);

}
```

and the error message is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<super*>::push_back(super&)'
```

I have been stuck with this problem for a couple of days and I just can not seem to get around it. I do not want exact code on how to do this, but just a head start so I can try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.add `super` to the list

```
TeamA.push_back(hptr);
TeamB.push_back(vptr);
```

We can see from the error message that the `target` list stores the pointer to a `super` object, so you should use `target.push_back(tptr)` instead of `target.push_back(*tptr)`; `tptr` refers to a pointer of a super. *tptr is a `super` object.

2.compare the `stl::list` element

You can specify [a custom sort predicate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).

```
bool compareSuper(const super* a, const super* b) {
    return (a->speed) > (b->speed);
 }

 TeamA.sort(compareSuper); // TeamA is in decreasing order after sort
 TeamB.sort(compareSuper); // TeamB is in decreasing order after sort
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for list comparison you can write your own function with needed logic.

Second, you have a little problem in `addtarget` function. Your `target` variable have type "list of pointers to super", but in line `target.push_back(*tptr)` you trying add object object to list instead pointer to object.

Third, if you want merge two lists, you can use `list::merge` with your comparison function for your classes. About merging you can [read here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/).